# How to retrieve the date the user was created in Firebase using VueJS 3

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, vuejs3

I have a "profiles" collection in the Firestore database. The collection has most of the data I need, but the date of creation of the user. In the "Authentication" DB, there is a created column that has the date the user was created.

I want to display the date the user was created in the list. All the data being retrieved from the Firebase collection "Profiles" is displaying fine, but I am having issues getting the data from the authentication. I am getting an N/A as a fallback in case the date is not successfully retrieved. So far all my cells are showing N/A.

The v-for is looping into profiles but not authentication, maybe that is the issue?

What am I missing?

```
 <tr v-for="user in profiles" :key="user.id">
            <td scope="col-1" class="fs-7 py-2 px-3">{{ formatDate(user) }}</td>
              </td>
</tr>
```

The script is here:

```
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";
import { db } from "../firebase";

import {
  collection, deleteDoc, doc,
  getDocs, updateDoc,
} from "firebase/firestore";

export default {
    setup() {
        const profiles = ref([]);
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const profilesSnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "profiles"));
                profiles.value = profilesSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
                    return {
                        id: doc.id,
                        ...doc.data(),
                    };
                });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
            }
        };
        onMounted(async () => {
            await fetchData();
        });
        const formatDate = (user) => {
  if (user.metadata && user.metadata.creationTimestamp) {
    const date = new Date(user.metadata.creationTimestamp.seconds * 1000); // Assuming timestamp is in seconds
    return date.toLocaleDateString(); 
  } else {
    return 'N/A'; // This is the value I am getting now.
  }
};
        return {
          profiles,
          formatDate, 
        };
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Authentication client-side SDKs (such as the one for JavaScript that you're using) can give you access to the creation timestamp of the currently signed-in user, but not on profile information from other users.

If you need this information across all users, you should store it in the database - like you do with other profile information.

Comment: I have added the timestamp field to the profiles collection to be added when the user registers. It is working. It is using the sever timestamp, which is fine for this use case. Thanks for the advice.